# How do I read current solution configuration from inside MSBuild task?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

`$(ConfigurationName)` provides access to the current configuration of Visual Studio project.

How do I access the current configuration of the containing solution?

Comment: Setting the build log output window detail level to "Diagnostic" and running a build does not show "Mixed Platforms" when I have that selected as the solution configuration so its not obvious.